# Core animation — performance issues with image-based layers

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, core-animation

My app basically consists of about 30 full sized images which are concurrently animated. Many of the images are transparent or semi-transparent and overlaid on top of other images.

The animations are simple (repeated opacity changes mainly) usually of type CAKeyframeAnimation. Here's an example of a typical animation.

First I load the image as follows:

```
   UIImage *layerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:baseImageName];
    CGImageRef image = [layerImage CGImage];
    layerToAdd.opacity = 0;
    [layerToAdd setContents:(__bridge id)image];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layerToAdd];
```

Then I add the animation:

```
            CAKeyframeAnimation *layerAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
            layerAnimation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],
                                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],
                                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.9],
                                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],
                                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0], nil];
            layerAnimation.keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],
                                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.750],
                                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.756],
                                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.759],
                                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1], nil];

            layerAnimation.duration = 60;
            layerAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
            [layer addAnimation:layerAnimation forKey:@"WC3d"];
```

It seemed to be performing OK on the simulator but when I added a new layer where I animated on position, it was very clear that that particular animation was very choppy. As a test, I then removed all the opacity-based animations, and noticed that the position animation became smooth.

So, is my approach to animation (i.e. loading images into layers and then animating mainly on the opacity property of that layer) all wrong? Is there a better way to achieve this (e.g. create the animation in a separate tool and then import this animation somehow)? Are there any obvious things I should be doing to improve performance?

Many thanks.

Comment: I've been doing this o the simulator until now. My computer is an early 2013 15" MacBook Pro Retina and very fast. I would assume therefore that performance would be even worse on an actual device.

Comment: As I wanted to profile the app, specifically the core animation part and to this I needed to provision on a device — so I installed it on my 3rd generation iPad. What is strange is that the performance on the iPad is much better than on my laptop, the animations are perfectly smooth. I wasn't expecting that. I will try to optimise the performance anyway as it can't hurt.

Comment: having the same exact issue. did you work out what the issue was? is there a better way than using image based layer + animating opacity

Comment: Hi, sorry to hear about the problems. In the end I abandoned that approach. My real problem was that I was using full size images, whereas now where I use smaller images (just the parts of the screen where I want to animate). I also use CAEmitterLayers — they are incredibly powerful and with a little creativity you can create quite a wide range of effects with them. For other animation I use frame-based animation — so I build the animation frame by frame in a graphics programme and often combine it with other animations (e.g.moving it along a path). Let me know if that helps and good luck.